# AWS EC2のディスク容量について

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, filesystems

AWSのEC2を使用しています。
デバイスタイプ EBS
先ほどディスク使用量が100%になりまして、不要なファイルを削除したのですが100%のままでした。
lsofの確認や再起動など試したのですが空き容量が増えないのですが
何か使用方法が間違っているのでしょうか？

**追記**
確認は df -hです。 ディスク総容量は75Gで削除したディレクトリ以下のデータ容量は1.8Gです。 ログははかれていないようです。 TABの入力補間もできないくらいです。 ./-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

以下のファイル!?が出来ていたのが気になります。
-rw------- 1 root root 16G Aug 31 05:21 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/resource1_wc
-rw------- 1 root root 16G Aug 31 05:21 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/resource1

Comment: 空き容量はどうやって確認しましたか？あと、不要なファイルを削除した時のファイルの総サイズはいくつで、どの程度の空き容量が見込めたが、結果はこうだったと、パーセンテージではなくByteで表記すると分かりやすいかと思います。1%もピンきりですので……。また、サービスなどのログが吐き出されてはいませんか？なにか書き込みが発生して圧迫している可能性はないでしょうか？

Comment: 追加情報は質問文中に追記していただけますか？他の回答者の方への参考になり回答がつきやすくなります。質問は`編集`リンクから修正が可能です。

Comment: あと可能であれば`lsof`の結果を教えてもらえますか？既に回答にもありますが容量の大きなファイルを探してある場合、ファイル名で`lsof`を`grep`して絞るといいです。個人的に私ならログを疑いますが……。

Comment: `No space left on device` に関しては i-node の枯渇の可能性もありますので、`df -i` を実行して確認することをお勧めします。

Comment: `df -h` と `df -i`、`du -sh /*` の結果を質問に追記してください。/sys/ は仮想ファイルシステムなので多分は無いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

一般論的ですが、

- 空いた容量を他のプロセスが食い潰していませんか？

  - ログ、ファイル生成など
- 容量の大きいファイルを確認しましたか？

  - `sudo find / -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lha {} \; 2>/dev/null` で100MB以上のファイルを一覧できます

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ギガ単位(1.8G)でデータを削除しましたので他のプロセスでここまで一気に食いつぶすのはないかなと思いました。

Answer (score 0):

大きなファイルを削除したのにディスク容量が空かない場合、そのファイルをどれかのプロセスがまだ使っている可能性があります。

使用中のファイルを削除した場合、そのファイルはすぐにはディスク上からは消えず、使い終わった時に消えます。それまで空き容量は増えません。

心当たりのあるプロセスがあれば、そのプロセスを終了させてみてください。

---

もう一点気づいたので、自分の回答に追記します。

ファイルシステムにもよりますが、
root 権限があると、使用量が 100% になっても実はまだ書き込めます。

つまり、ディスクの容量から数%を引き算して、そこが 100% となるようになっています。
それ以上は一般ユーザでは書き込めません。root 権限があれば書き込めます。
root 権限でそれ以上書いた場合、`df` では相変わらず 100% であり、
それ以上の数値 (110%とか) にはなりません。

ご質問の状態は、「root 権限でそれ以上書いた」状態になっているのだと思います。
その場合は、ファイルをもっと削除していけば、そのうち 100% 未満になり、
一般ユーザで書き込めるようになります。

Comment: @hhy 別の可能性に気づいたので回答に追記してみました。